# How to run ts-node-dev with PM2 in Debian?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have Node.js backend with typescript, mongodb. And i have try to run my app with command: `pm2 start ts-node-dev --name my-app --watch --ignore-watch="node_modules" --interpreter ts-node --interpreter-args="--transpile-only" -- src/app.ts`

but its return error:
`[PM2][ERROR] Script not found: /var/myapp.com/Backend/ts-node-dev`

My package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/app.ts",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts",
    "format": "eslint src/**/*.ts --fix"
  },
```

How to run this node.js app typescript?